# How to get rid of the blank parts from the sides of a container in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

while using containers in bootstrap, i found that both the sides of a container is left with spaces. So how to remove those spaces, or how to expand the width of container

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


**<div class="container" style="background-color: black; height: 500px;"></div>**

<div style="background-color: skyblue; height: 500px;"></div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be you are looking for `.container-fluid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap CSS container has "max-width: 1170px;"

1. Override the CSS (But this will cause a lot of other design problems):

   .container {
     max-width: 100%;
   }
2. Or Use **container-fluid** class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

If that doesn't work try resetting the CSS before attaching the bootstrap stylesheet.

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

you can put it in a CSS file and attach it before attaching the bootstrap.min.css file.

Comment: don't use  *{} because you will overwrite a lot of things. Use .container{padding:0;margin:10px 0;}